# Adding 2 Variables into one returns 0

Tags: php

I tried adding 2 Variables together, but it only outputs a 0. What can i do?
My Code:

```
<?php
$s1 = file_get_contents('https://www.reyfm.de/get/1/s1.php');
$s2 = file_get_contents('https://www.reyfm.de/get/1/s2.php');
//$fk = file_get_contents('fk.txt');
$sum = $s1 + $s2;
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
print($sum);
?>
```

**Please help me, thanks! :)
(Just some random text, so i can post this Question... la la lu can i post this now?)
(Just some random text, so i can post this Question... la la lu can i post this now?)
(Just some random text, so i can post this Question... la la lu can i post this now?)
(Just some random text, so i can post this Question... la la lu can i post this now?)
(Just some random text, so i can post this Question... la la lu can i post this now?)**

Comment: Protip: If the automated tools tell you your question is bad don't add random text to try to get around it. Instead, read [ask] and then fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use settype() in the php and set them to.integer and simple add them 
Or you can do this:
  $s1 = "'".$si."'"; 
 Do this for s2 also
 and add them
Cause if you have a var like this

$s1 ='1'; $s2 = '2' ;
echo $s1 +$s2 ;

It will give output 3 for sure